# why choose 1024 for when random point generation in PCL application

Tags: point-cloud-library

I have noticed in most of the PCl example, they choose 1024 for random point generation. Is there a special reason for choosing 1024 ?

```
cloud->points[i].x = 1024 * rand () / (RAND_MAX + 1.0f);
cloud->points[i].y = 1024 * rand () / (RAND_MAX + 1.0f);
cloud->points[i].z = 1024 * rand () / (RAND_MAX + 1.0f);
```

Comment: 1024 * rand() creates negative integers whereas rand() by itself only positive. But I do not know why they do 1024 * rand() rather than just 2 * rand().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a reason at all, I guess they just chose a random value.

It is a matter of normalization. `rand()` provides normalized values between [0, 1]. If you multiply by 1024, you'll have values between [0, 1024] = [0, 2^10]. The only reason I could see is if you have your boundaries delimited in a [0, 2^N] range, you will make a lot of tasks easier (e.g. working with hierarchical structures).
Anyway mind that you can normalize between the values that you want, depending on your needs.